# CodeIgniter Mod_Rewrite issues

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Having issues removing index.php? from the URL:

```
http://localhost/index.php?/reset_password
```

With htaccess file:

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

CI Settings:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I looked at the other threads on here with similar problems but none of their htaccess files work. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: If you can link to the posts with the other `.htaccess` setups that didn't work for you, that would be a great help.

Comment: the first 5 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CodeIgniter+Mod_Rewrite+issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen that `.htaccess` setup before, although it may work. I've used this for every CI project I've done, give it a try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # If the start of the URL doesn't match one of these...
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|cache|themes|uploads)

    # Route through index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Add don't forget this in `config.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And remember: This will not "remove" `index.php` from your URL automatically, but rather route the request through it if it isn't present. If you have hardcoded links with `index.php` in them, they'll have to be changed or you'll need additional `.htaccess` configuration. If you are using the CI url functions like `base_url()`, `site_url()`, and `anchor()`, they won't use `index.php` if you have it blank in your config above.

Comment: Interesting, I had it at $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; so after removing it my url is now: http://localhost/?/reset_password. Probably some other settings?

Comment: How are you arriving at that URL to begin with? You don't have `$config['enable_query_strings']` on do you? If so, you need to turn it off (don't worry it's not what you think, it's useless). Does the correct page load with your current URL, or does it ignore everything after the `?`?

Comment: Working now. Thanks a lot. I need to make sure that changing query_strings doesn't break my site so I'll look into what that is. Again, thanks! So many things to consider.

Comment: Read up on what it actually does, I think you want instead: `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

If name of my site is **codeIgniter_ci_intro**

I used code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeIgniter_ci_intro//index.php/$1 [L]
```

and I changed in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```